# Clojure first and rest

Tags: function, clojure, symbols

Why do I get 2 different values for

```
(apply (first '(+ 1 2)) (rest '(+ 1 2)))
> 2
```

and

```
(apply + '(1 2))
> 3
```

when

```
(first '(+ 1 2)) 
> +
```

and

```
(rest '(+ 1 2))
> (1 2)
```

I tried reduce and got the same value

```
(reduce (first '(+ 1 2)) (rest '(+ 1 2)))
> 2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your trouble is that you're trying to call the symbol `'+` rather than the function `+`. When you call a symbol, it tries to look up the symbol in the first argument (for example, if it had been `{'a 1 '+ 5 'b 2}` you would have gotten `5`). If you pass a second argument, that value gets returned instead of `nil` if the symbol can't be found in the first argument. So when you call `('+ 1 2)`, it tries to look up `'+` in 1 and fails, so it returns 2.

Incidentally, this is the difference between creating lists with `'(+ 1 2)` and `(list + 1 2)`. The former creates a list of the symbols +, 1 and 2. Since '1 and 1 are the same, that's fine. But the symbol '+ is not the Var clojure.core/+, so the latter gets the value of the Var while the former just gets the symbol. So if you'd done `(list + 1 2)`, your could would have worked as written.

Answer (score 2):

(first '(+ 1 2)) is a symbol.

```
user=> (class (first '(+ 1 2)))
clojure.lang.Symbol
user=> (apply (symbol "+") [1 2])
2
user=> (apply (eval (symbol "+")) [1 2])
3
user=> (apply (eval (first '(+ 1 2))) (rest '(+ 1 2)))
3

user=> (class (first [+ 1 2]))
clojure.core$_PLUS_
user=> (apply (first [+ 1 2]) (rest '(+ 1 2)))
3
```