# Generating a symbol from a string and applying it as a function

Tags: clojure

I'm just learning clojure, and I'm hitting a wall.

I'm trying to read an arithmetic expression as an infix string and process it in Clojure.

e.g. "1 + 2" -> (+ 1 2)

I read in the "+" and turn it into a symbol like this:

```
(def plus (symbol "clojure.core" "+"))
```

Which appears to work properly, but when I call it, I don't get what I'm expecting:

```
user=> plus
+

user=> (plus 1 1)
1
user=> (plus 1 2)
2
user=> (plus 1 2 3)
ArityException Wrong number of args (3) passed to: Symbol  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: @yonki the reason is "+" is a string in the original expression

Comment: It's just an exercise to learn the language better.  The point isn't to add things together, the point is to explore how symbols and functions interact with each other in clojure.

Comment: Sorry for removing comment, wanted to make more meaningful answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure first and rest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054988/clojure-first-and-rest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbols have a function attached to them by default.  The function that is attached to them by default is look this key up in a map.  That is why your plus behaves oddly. It is attempting to look up elements in a map.

`(plus 1 1)`
This is really look the symbol + up in the map 1 and if not found return a default value of 1.

`(plus 1 2)`
Same as above except default value is 2.

[clojure docs for symbols](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Symbols)

Comment: So is the (hypothetical) map in the first argument looking for a definition of the symbol `plus`?

Comment: @Will it's just a regular old map, e.g. `('+ {'+ 3})` -> 3.

Comment: @Will: Yes. More specifically, it's looking for a value mapped to key `plus`. Even more specifically it's not the map itself but the invoke method of the Symbol class.

Comment: @Will It is looking up the symbol +. `(def plus '+) (plus {'+ 4 'plus 5})` will return 4 not 5.

Answer (score 0):

What's your reason to write such code? If you want to have function called `plus` which gonna be `+` synonym just write `(def plus +)`.

Clojure `+` is normal function. You can use it like `(+ 1 2 3 4 5)`. There's no reason to turn it into symbol.

Clojure have no operators at all. Only functions and macros.

Still, if you insist on using `symbol` you need to eval it like so

`(def plus (eval (symbol "clojure.core/+")))`.

Have a look on class of `(symbol "clojure.core/+")` and `+` itself.

`(class (symbol "clojure.core/+")) ;;clojure.lang.Symbol`

`(class +) ;;clojure.core$_PLUS_`

Symbols themselves are not callable as functions which are "under this symbols". If you want to "turn symbol into callable function" you have to eval it.

Comment: If I type `(eval (plus 1 1))` it runs, but I get the same behavior as before.

Comment: Then try `((eval plus) 1 2 3 4)`. Your code works as: take what `(plus 1 1)` returned and eval it. Mine works as: eval `plus` and call it for following args.

Comment: Symbols implement AFn und thus are invokable. Or type ``(eval `(~plus 1 1 1))``.

Comment: Aha!  So I call `eval` on the SYMBOL, which tells clojure to do the lookup and find the underlying `clojure.core/+`, which I can then use to process the arguments.  Ok, got it.

Comment: You don't need `eval`. You can also use `(ns-resolve 'clojure.core '+)` to get the var mapped by the symbol.

Comment: @Alex Is there an operational difference between `(ns-resolve 'clojure-core '+)` and `(eval (symbol "clojure.core" "+"))`?  I know that `symbol` can take a couple optional arguments, which is what was tripping me up before.  Well, and symbol navel-gazing aside, I do need to have a string as my starting point for this exercise.

Comment: @Will ns-resolve is just a lower-level function, specifically for looking up the var mapped by a symbol. eval does that, and lots of other stuff such as invoking functions.